# Shared ephemeral file storage between Fargate tasks per Step Function run

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-fargate, aws-step-functions, amazon-efs, data-security

I am trying to run a service that does some analysis on 3rd party code using AWS step function and 3 separate fargate tasks that need some kind of shared storage. Two of the tasks are trusted, but one will be running arbitrary unchecked 3rd party code. The results of each step need to somehow be accessible by the following step without compromising data security.

The flow of the service is this:

1. Step 1 pulls code from storage (originally uploaded by a user, can be S3) and does some operations on it. This step can be trusted, as the 3rd party code is never run.
2. Step 2 runs the code, and somehow needs to store the output. This step must be untrusted as the code is user provided and may be malicious. This means that it cannot be granted S3 read access to pull the code (since it could pull some from another user), and it cannot be granted S3 write access. Somehow it needs to get the code from step 1, and eventually send its output to step 3.
3. Step 3 does an operation on the result of step 2, and uploads the results to S3 to be pulled by a separate web service. Step 3 is trusted, and therefor can be granted S3 access.

My thought on how to deal with this was to see if there was some kind of shared ephemeral storage that could be created at the beginning of the step function, and shared between the fargate tasks, and then deleted as soon as the step function terminates. Each fargate task should be able to only access data from the shared storage associated with that particular step function run or we run into the same issue as if we had given all 3 tasks S3 access.

Is something like this possible? Everything I could find on EFS seemed to require manually creating an endpoint with dedicated IAM roles, which wouldn't work for this use case since these step functions are user triggered. Is there some other way to do this that would allow isolation between tasks, but access to some shared resources (which themselves should be isolated per step-function)?

Comment: Ephemeral volumes are, by-definition, not persistent. The Fargate ephemeral volumes disappear as soon as the Fargate task stops. They cannot be shared across task executions. Do your Fargate Tasks not have a Task role and Task Execution Role? Those are the roles used for the EFS volume attachment. I'm not sure the step functions being  user triggered actually effect that at all.

Comment: So I might have been using some incorrect terminology with the term "ephemeral storage" but essentially what I mean by that is that it should be ephemeral per-step-function-run. It's possible doing that will mean adding a creation and cleanup step to the step function, as long as it is accessible to all tasks generated by that step function run, and not accessible to anything else, and deleted on exit.

Comment: "it cannot be granted S3 read access to pull the code (since it could pull some from another user)" if you pass a presigned url between steps you can remove that concern, since presigned URLs specify a particular object.  You can provide one for the job's output data as well.

Comment: No, you were using the correct terminology. Amazon calls the storage provided to Fargate containers "ephemeral". And that storage disappears forever as soon as the Fargate task exits.

Answer (score 1):

I understand your two requirements to be:  (1) isolate the file artefacts per step function execution and (2) accommodate reading and writing by both trusted and untrusted sources.

Consider the following, relying only on S3:

1. Capture a unique ID that identifies the execution in a Pass State.  Generate a UUID with the `States.UUID()` [intrinsic function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html#asl-intrsc-func-uuid-generate).  Or instead use the Execution ID from the [context object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-contextobject.html) as `$$.Execution.Id`.
2. A Lambda task stages the input files to S3. Use the execution's random ID as the S3 objects' [prefix](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-prefixes.html):   `/<random-id>/input.zip`.
3. Another Lambda task creates two [presigned URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-presigned-url.html). The untrusted Fargate Task 2 will use them to read the inputs and write its output.  The untrusted task does not even know the `random-id`.  It just gets time-limited obfuscated URLs.
4. Do the work.  Your trusted tasks can access the `/<random-id>/` S3 files directly, the untrusted task only via the presigned URLs.
5. A Lambda task deletes all the files with the prefix `/<random-id>/`.

Requirement #1 is satisfied with a the random prefix.  Requirement #2 is satisfied with the presigned URLs.